# Sort by the 3 top highest values in a column (with time frame filter)? Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am getting the following rows when I perform this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM statetable 
where "machineName" ='Main01'
ORDER BY statetable_ndx DESC LIMIT 100
```

| machineName | state | stateDuratio | t_stamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Main01 | 3 | 12002 | 2023-06-29 21:21:04.152 |
| Main01 | 5 | 360169 | 2023-06-29 21:20:58.144 |
| Main01 | 3 | 3002 | 2023-06-29 21:20:34.013 |
| Main01 | 5 | 45024 | 2023-06-29 21:20:18.983 |
| Main01 | 4 | 18007 | 2023-06-29 21:20:12.972 |

... and so on...

Now my question is, I am trying to query to get the highest 3 top values from the stateDuration column.
So far this is what I have tried, and it's now sorting by the highest 3 sorted out by StateDuration..

```
SELECT "State",
       "StateName", 
Max("StateDuration") as "StateDuration"
FROM statetable  
where "machineName" ='Main01' 
Group by "State", "StateName"
ORDER BY "StateDuration" DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

**However, the problem for me is when I try to also filter by a time frame:**

when I try to add a timeframe line (like this line in the following query: AND t_stamp >= '2023-08-10 16:30:00' AND t_stamp <= '2023-08-14 00:30:00')
I don't get any result and I don't understand why.
Does someone has any clue for me?

```
SELECT "State","StateName", 
Max("StateDuration") as "StateDuration"
FROM statetable 
where "machineName" ='Main01'
AND t_stamp >= '2023-08-10 16:30:00' AND t_stamp <= '2023-08-14 00:30:00'
Group by "State", "StateName"
ORDER BY "StateDuration" DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: There is no StateName column in your data example. *I am trying to query to get the highest 3 top values from the stateDuration column* it seems in your example that you are trying top 3 StateDuration per "State","StateName" and yet you are using limit 100. What datatype is the t_stamp  column, do you really have records  between the interval  '2023-08-10 16:30:00' AND '2023-08-14 00:30:00' ? See [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) #5 , #3 and update the question

Comment: The StateName column is not in my data example but that's another column in my table with extra info I need. I wish to only sort the StateDuration column though. The datatype aI am using for the t_stamp column is "timestamp without timezone" and I have data for the range timeframe I am trying to query.

Comment: Please disregard. You're right I did not have data for that timeframe. I did not notice the server was querying on the wrong table. This was such a dumb question. :/ My bad.